# Did Chava tell Adam she was giving him fruit from the etz ha'das?

Tags: trees, parashat-bereishit, fruits, adam, eve-chava

When Chava gave Adam fruit from the etz ha'das to eat did she tell him where the fruit was coming from or not?

Comment: I'll try to find a definitive source, but I remember reading that she did not, but Adam was culpable because he did not ask.

Comment: See [hagahos RD"L on Pirke Rebi Eliezer chapter 13 # 46](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21858&pgnum=95)

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of dispute. See here in an old speech of mine:

> Beraishis Rabba (19:5) and (20:8) relate a three-way dispute as to why Adam ate from the tree.
>
> Rabbi Aivu quotes the ... pasuk: vattitten gam li-ishah eemah vayyochal. and she gave also to her husband with her and he ate. Rabbi Aivu derives from the pasuk that he ate because she gave it to him. He says, Suhchatuh Anuhvim vinuhsinu lo. The etz hadaas was a grape vine, and Chava squeezed the grapes into grape juice and gave it to him. Thus, he did not know that he was partaking of the forbidden fruit and was therefore acting either out of shogeg or peshiah...
>
> In contrast, Rabbi Simlai quotes beraishit 3:17 , where Hashem says he will punish Adam Ki shumatu likol ishtechu, vatochal min-hu-etz, “because you listened to the voice of your wife and ate from the fruit.” Listening to the voice of someone generally means listening to an argument put forth by that person and agreeing to the validity of his or her argument. Thus, according to Rabbi Simlai, this pasuk implies that Chava presented a compelling argument to Adam, and Adam, persuaded by her argument, ate the fruit...
>
> Finally, the Chachamim disagree with Rabbi Simlai’s understanding of the pasuk Ki shumatu likol ishtechu vatochal min-hu-etz: Rabbi Simlai posited that shumatu likol ishtechu meant listening to Chava’s words, but if so, the pasuk should have said Ki shumatu lidivray ishtechu. Kol implies voice, not words, so the Chachamim claim that Chava began weeping and crying to him until he ate from the etz.

Thus, according to Rabbi Aivu, he did not know. According to Rabbi Simlai and the Chachamim, he did.

Answer (score 1):

Baal haTurim on 3:12 says she forced him to eat it "by beating him with the stick of the tree."* I have heard this interpreted by my rabbeim that she cried hysterically and that to him it was like "being beaten with a stick" - a strong impact - and that is what forced him to eat it.

It follows that he knew what he was eating of.

*Note this fits the language of the verse - "...gave me *of the tree* and I ate."

Comment: I don't understand how the fact that her crying impelled him to eat it implies that he knew whereof he eat.

Comment: @msh210 otherwise why would she need to go to such lengths to get him to eat it?

Comment: @nikmasi, maybe he didn't like raw citron (and who can blame him). Or some other reason.

Comment: @msh210 I always thought that was the point of content between them, like nikmasi wrote.